# Using REGEXP in a loop reading from other table in MySQL

Tags: regex, loops, iteration

Have a question about the use of REGEXP in a query. I have a table in my database with near 553,000 records (34,517 x 16). And also have a list of values which need to find in that table. Using REGEXP I have success in find some values using this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `TableA` WHERE ((*desiredvalue* REGEXP 'a|b|c|d...'));
```

Now, the list of *desiredvalues* growth from 20 to 1700, so, exists some way to put this new values in a single column  in a `Table B` and search in the `TableA` using a reading loop over the new table. Mi first instinct was save the consult and paste the all 1700 records, but the idea is do it automatic when the `Table B`be updated.

Here's is an example of my initial matrix (all values are 14 character strings):

```
    +-----+---+---+---+---+-----+----+
    |Group|SP1|SP2|SP3|SP4|.....|SP15|
    +-----+---+---+---+---+-----+----+
    |G1   |a  |b  |c  |d  |.....|x   |
    |G2   |   |b  |h  |d  |.....|z   |
    |G4   |a  |b  |   |m  |.....|r   |
    |G5   |o  |p  |q  |r  |.....|h   |
    +-----+---+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

The idea if I have a list with of values val=(a,c,h,r,p), I obtain this result:

```
    +---+-----+
    |val|Group|
    +---+-----+
    |a  |G1   |
    |a  |G4   |
    |c  |G1   |
    |h  |G2   |
    |r  |G4   |
    |r  |G5   |
    |p  |G5   |
    +---+-----+
```

Thanks!

Christian

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the final output should look like?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added an example to the original question.